# How to count number of times logical condition is met per column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing some values where I would like to check for each column, count the number of times a logical condition is met.
I can manage this in base R, however I am struggling with the dplyr package.

An example dataframe:

```
A = c(12,30,7,3,13) 
B = c(23,26,45,9,15) 
C = c(12,6,17,35,8)
D = c(22,10,9,20,16) 
X = c(45,24,77,83,27) 
df<- data.frame(A, B, C, D, X)


> A   B   C   D   X
  12  23  12  22  45
  30  26  6   10  24
  7   45  17  9   77
  3   9   35  20  83
  13  15  8   16  27
```

I would like to return the number of rows for columns A to D where some operation between said column and X return TRUE, for example:
The number of occurrences where (2 * Col) + X > 90,

In base R you can do something like:

```
sum((2*df$A) - df$X > 90)
```

To return the number times the condition was met in column A, and then repeat for B, C and D.

I am wondering if there is a more succinct way to do this in dplyr, to return some data such as:

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   2   2
```

Where these values represent the number of times the condition was met in each column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use `2 * A:D + X`, since `- X` produces nothing. Your expected output better matches `+` anyway ...

### base R

```r
colSums(2*subset(df, select=A:D) + df$X > 90)
# A B C D 
# 1 3 2 2
```

This is a named-vector, not a frame.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
colSums(2*select(df, A:D) + df$X > 90)
```

returns the named-vector as the base R version did. If you want a frame instead, then

```r
summarize(df, across(A:D, ~ sum(2*. + X > 90)))
#   A B C D
# 1 1 3 2 2
```

Comment: Brilliant response, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` you could do something like this I think:

```
df %>% summarise(across(A:D, ~sum(2*. + X > 90)))
```

Although for things like this I quite like using `purrr::map_df`:

```
select(df, -X) %>% map_df(~sum(2*. + df$X > 90))
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected output.

Comment: I was just being lazy and put in a different condition because in the original question the condition `sum((2*df$A) - df$X > 90)` didn't match the expected output (it just gives all zeros). Updated to actually output what was expected.

Comment: I understand and agree, inconsistent data/output can be confusing. However, when doing so, it's often best to retain the "complexity" of the formula; in this case, it is comparing all non-`X` variables in a formula with `X`, so `everything()` is immediately a non-starter. Your edits have since remedied it, nice. (And thanks for the prod, I hadn't commented why I changed the formula as well :-)